# How to display the data or table in database in mysql as editable in ms access form? (Like List box as editable )

Tags: mysql, vba, database, ms-access

Am Using Ms-Access as front end and mysql as backend.
i displayed data from mysql i list box, i need to edit the data in the listbox itself.

Is there any other way that i can edit the data.

I tried several ways i can't find.

Thank in advance.

Need your help.

Form in list attached the image that i displayed in list view

[image]

```
    Option Compare Database
    Option Explicit
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim cmdtext As New ADODB.Command

Private Sub cmd_extract_Click()
Dim strfield As String
Dim strextract As String
Dim intItemsInList As Integer
Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim intCol As Integer
intItemsInList = Me![lstbox].ListCount
For intCounter = 0 To intItemsInList - 1
  Me![lstbox].RemoveItem 0
Next

strfield = Me.cmb1
If strfield = "ALL" Then
strextract = "SELECT *FROM emp_details JOIN dept_details ON emp_details.E_Dept = dept_details.D_Name ORDER BY Emp_Id  ASC;"
Set cmdtext.ActiveConnection = cn
cmdtext.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdtext.CommandText = strextract
Set rs = cmdtext.Execute
Me.lstbox.AddItem ("EMP-ID" & ";" & "EMP-NAME" & ";" & "EMP-DEPT" & ";" & "EMP-SALARY" & ";" & "DEPT_ID" & ";" & "DEPT_NAME" & ";" & "DEPT_HEAD")
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
With Me.lstbox
.AddItem (rs.Fields(0) & ";" & rs.Fields(1) & ";" & rs.Fields(2) & ";" & rs.Fields(3) & ";" & rs.Fields(4) & ";" & rs.Fields(5) & ";" & rs.Fields(6))
.ColumnHeads = True
rs.MoveNext
End With
Loop
End If
Else
strextract = "SELECT * FROM emp_details JOIN dept_details ON emp_details.E_Dept = dept_details.D_Name WHERE dept_details.D_Name = '" & strfield & "';"
Set cmdtext.ActiveConnection = cn
cmdtext.CommandType = adCmdText
cmdtext.CommandText = strextract
Set rs = cmdtext.Execute
'Me.lstbox.RowSourceType = "Value List"
Me.lstbox.AddItem ("EMP-ID" & ";" & "EMP-NAME" & ";" & "EMP-DEPT" & ";" & "EMP-SALARY" & ";" & "DEPT_ID" & ";" & "DEPT_NAME" & ";" & "DEPT_HEAD")
If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
Do While Not rs.EOF
With Me.lstbox
.AddItem (rs.Fields(0) & ";" & rs.Fields(1) & ";" & rs.Fields(2) & ";" & rs.Fields(3) & ";" & rs.Fields(4) & ";" & rs.Fields(5) & ";" & rs.Fields(6))
.ColumnHeads = True
rs.MoveNext
End With
Loop
End If
End If
End Sub

Public Sub Form_Load()
Dim cnnstring As String
cnnstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver};Server=localhost;Database=My_Project2;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
If cn.State = 0 Then
cn.Open cnnstring
End If
Dim cquery As String
cquery = "SELECT * FROM dept_details;"
'FULL OUTER JOIN dept_details ON emp_details.E-Dept = dept_details.D_NAME

With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn
.Source = cquery
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
.Open
End With
rs.MoveFirst

With Me.cmb1
.AddItem "ALL"
Do
cmb1.AddItem rs!D_Name
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim cnnstring As String
cnnstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 8.0 UNICODE Driver};Server=localhost;Database=My_Project2;Uid=root;Pwd=password;"
cn.Open cnnstring
Dim cquery As String
cquery = "SELECT * FROM dept_details;"
'FULL OUTER JOIN dept_details ON emp_details.E-Dept = dept_details.D_NAME

With rs
Set .ActiveConnection = cn
.Source = cquery
.LockType = adLockOptimistic
.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
.Open
End With
rs.MoveFirst

With Me.cmb1
.AddItem "ALL"
Do
cmb1.AddItem rs!D_Name
rs.MoveNext
Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
rs.Close
End Sub


Private Sub lstbox_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
'If cn.State = 1 Then
'cn.Close
'End If

Dim listid As Long
listid = Me.lstbox.Value
DoCmd.Close acForm, "Form_Form3"
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form4", OpenArgs:=listid
End Sub
```

Comment: How is the back end "connected" do you retrieve the data on the form opening/event or is it linked?  What ways did you try, can you summarise those?

Comment: backend is connected using adodb database with odbc drive. the data is retrieve in opening event of the form

Answer (score 0):

A listbox is for listing data, not editing data.

To view data in a similar way, and with the option to edit these, use a form in *DatasheetView*.

Place that in your main form as a *subform*.

Comment: in datasheet view only i can edit the only one column the empid that's not an advisable way to edit and save the data i think so.

Comment: Is there any other way apart from listbox and datasheet view?

Comment: I don't follow. If the recordset used as source is updatable, so is the form. Of course, read-only fields like an autonumber cannot be edited.

Comment: there is no autonumber fields, the record set is updatable only

Comment: There is a lot of code. It seems to fill the listbox and the combobox. As noted, such controls are read-only.

Comment: Yes i need a suggestion is there any other control to edit the data and save?

Comment: Yes. A bound (sub)form.